# How to get the height of a body element

Tags: jquery, css

Here the total height of all `<div>`'s are 900 pixels, but the jQuery function returns the height of the body as 577 pixels. (If I remove the body CSS, it's working).

Is there a solution for this problem?

```
$j(function() {
    alert($j("body").height());
})

html, body {
    height:100%;
}

<div style="height:200px">header</div>
<div style="height:500px">content</div>
<div style="height:200px">footer</div>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Set

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
```

instead of `height: 100%`.

The result jQuery returns is correct, because you've set the height of the body to 100%, and that's probably the height of the viewport. These three DIVs were causing an overflow, because there weren't enough space for them in the BODY element. To see what I mean, set a border to the BODY tag and check where the border ends.

Comment: While this may work for this case, this isn't an answer to the asked question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304378/jquery-web-page-height

Comment: this body { min-height: 100%; } was a really good suggestion.

Comment: Should that CSS setting be for **html** and not for **head** as written?

Comment: @Robert Koritnik: thanks. Don't know how I didn't notice the typo for so long.

Comment: thanks @Rafael , even after so many years, your answer is still appreciated.

Answer (score 42):

Simply use

```
$(document).height() // - $('body').offset().top
```

and / or

```
$(window).height()
```

instead of `$('body').height();`

Comment: this is also nice one Mr.OderWat, but i am getting 8px extra than that of actual size.(by using $(document).height() ).

Comment: Those 8 pixels "more" are correct. They are the margins of the document. You may either use: body { height:100%; margin:0 } or you substract the offset using $(document).height()-$("body").offset().top

Comment: $("body").offset().top works for equal margins on body but if the bottom margin is set specifically, it won't work.  Also, I tried $("body").css("margin-bottom") but that returns with the units and it may not always be in pixels.  Are there any other ways to find out the "more"?

Answer (score 2):

$(document).height() seems to do the trick and gives the total height including the area which is only visible through scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the body height being returned is the visible height. If you need the total page height, you could wrap your div tags in a containing div and get the height of that.

Answer (score 0):

We were trying to avoid using the IE specific

```
$window[0].document.body.clientHeight
```

And found that the following jQuery will not consistently yield the same value but eventually does at some point in our page load scenario which worked for us and maintained cross-browser support:

```
$(document).height()
```

Comment: You need to indent by 4 spaces to create a code block, you were one short on each.