# jQuery web page height

Tags: jquery, height, html

Let's say that a web page is twice the height of the browser window (thus there's a scroll bar). How do I retrieve the height of the web page in jQuery?

Answer (score 141, accepted):

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport

$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning browser viewport. That's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 16):

You could use the `height()` of the document.

`$(document).height();`

Answer (score 0):

This can work also.

```
$('body').height();
```

Comment: yeah, but it doesn't work when not the full screen is filled by the body