# Get web page height through jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get the height of viewable web page of browser with jquery? I have tried `$(window).height()` but it did not return accurate result.. Thanks..

Comment: That's how you should do it.  Can you explain more as to what was inaccurate?  What browser is inaccurate?  What it should be instead?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304378/jquery-web-page-height

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/height/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the jQuery documentation:

```
$(window).height();   // returns height of browser viewport
$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document
```

Answer (score 0):

```
height=$(window).height();
```