# Section height should cover the whole screen in all resolutions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on one project and client has a requirement that each section should cover the whole screen by width and height too.

I used media queries for that i'm successfully set section to cover the 100% width of browser this is not difficult for any developer. Problem is that i can't figure out how to set media queries for height i mean i cannot set height in % and if we set height in pixels then it cannot cover the whole screen in all resolutions.

Below is the image what actually i'm trying to say. 
[image]

Above the section is fixed header and below the section is fixed footer.

Now i need to know is there a way by using css or javascript/jquery or any other framework that section will cover the whole screen between footer and header no need to scroll to see the whole section. User should see the whole section without scrolling down.

Comment: I only use media queries for height but i cannot set tons of media queries for each pixel

Comment: So you haven't tried anything yet? Look into flexbox. Alternatively JS could be used to do this.

Comment: Can you tell how do this with JS ?

Comment: Set their height to the page height minus header and footer height. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304378/jquery-web-page-height
Use $('header').height() to get the header height and the same with footer, and to set height do $('element').height(newHeight);

Answer (score 0):

Few solutions:
one is to use background-size:cover:

```
background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
```

you can read more about that option here: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

If you want to use % you have to make sure that all the parent elements have height set. If you don't set the height for the html and body, the browser can't calculate the %.

so add:

```
html,body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
}
```

The first approach will give you better visuals because it will keep the image ratio.