# How can I get the current document area size in javascript in IE, Firefox, Webkit?

Tags: javascript

I need cross-browser compatible Javascript code that will return me the height and width of the current document area in all three browsers (IE, Firefox, Webkit [Chrome/Safari]).  I don't need the entire window size (as it is on the desktop) but the height and width of the document as it pertains to CSS layout.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what I needed was much easier...

```
function getDocumentWidth() {   
    return document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
}

function getDocumentHeight() {
    return document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
// Calc visible screen bounds (this code is common)
var w = 0, h = 0;
if (typeof(window.innerWidth) === 'number') {// не msie
    w = window.innerWidth;
    h = window.innerHeight;
} else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight)) {
    w = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    h = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}
var sx = 0, sy = 0;
if (typeof window.pageYOffset === 'number') {
    sx = window.pageXOffset;
    sy = window.pageYOffset;
} else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollLeft || document.body.scrollTop)) {
    sx = document.body.scrollLeft;
    sy = document.body.scrollTop;
} else if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollLeft || document.documentElement.scrollTop)) {
    sx = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    sy = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
var winHeight = h + sy;
var winWidth = w + sx;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is from some other site, which I forgot the actually, but, full credit to whom it belongs, not me. Here it is:

```
function f_clientWidth()
        {
            return f_filterResults(
                        window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : 0,
                        document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : 0,
                        document.body ? document.body.clientWidth : 0
                    );
        }

        function f_clientHeight()
        {
            return f_filterResults
                    (
                        window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : 0,
                        document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : 0,
                        document.body ? document.body.clientHeight : 0
                    );
        }

        function f_scrollLeft()
        {
            return f_filterResults
                    (
                        window.pageXOffset ? window.pageXOffset : 0,
                        document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollLeft : 0,
                        document.body ? document.body.scrollLeft : 0
                    );
        }

        function f_scrollTop()
        {
            return f_filterResults
                    (
                        window.pageYOffset ? window.pageYOffset : 0,
                        document.documentElement ? document.documentElement.scrollTop : 0,
                        document.body ? document.body.scrollTop : 0
                    );
        }

        function f_filterResults(n_win, n_docel, n_body)
        {
            var n_result = n_win ? n_win : 0;

            if(n_docel && (!n_result || (n_result > n_docel)))
            {
                n_result = n_docel;
            }

            return n_body && (!n_result || (n_result > n_body)) ? n_body : n_result;
        }
```

Usage is simple:

For width, call: f_clientWidth(), and so on...

Comment: I believe the source of it is : http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html, but I might be wrong.

Comment: yeah @HoLyVieR, u r right :) below is d source 4 above post...full credit to the author:
http://www.softcomplex.com/docs/get_window_size_and_scrollbar_position.html

Answer (score -1):

off the top of my head, would getting the height of the body work? with jQuery something like

```
$("body").css("height")
```

UPDATE: Assuming you are using jQuery ( why wouldn't you ;-) ) then [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806402/how-to-get-body-height-using-jquery) answers the question by adding this to your css when using the above solution.

```
head { height: 100%; }
body { min-height: 100%; }
```

This should also work

```
$(window).height()
```

It will include the margins though, in case you're getting more height than you think you should be.