# height of page with jQuery

Tags: jquery

What is the best way to measure the height of the entire page, and not just a screen. The reason I am asking is because i need to add an overlay div that should cover it entirely. Perhaps i can measure the height and add some more pixels for good measure?

If i do something like this, is it a move in the right direction of is there a better way?

```
$('#myOverlay').height($('#myPage').height() + 100) ;
```

Comment: So what you actually want is the height of viewport?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806402/how-to-get-body-height-using-jquery and http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/finding-real-body-height-using-jquery/ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider using a fixed positioned overlay, instead of absolute, you won't need the screen's height, but it will cover it all the way. try it here : http://jsfiddle.net/c4uzQ/9/

```
.overlay
{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: #909090;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity: 0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Comment: Setting width and height is redundant, or is there a specific reason as to why you are doing that?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. It might not necessary at all. To be hones I can't remember what the reason was.  Could have been a browser related fix, I'm assuming legacy IE if any, or I could have been too thorough. ;) After all. the more the merrier...

Answer (score 1):

**CSS/HTML method for overlay**

If you want an overlay to cover another element or viewport it's doable by only using CSS/HTML which will be alot faster and also works on browsers where JavaScript is disabled.

**CSS example**

By using absolute positiion we can tell the browser to fill an entire container with a the overlay element, as long as the container element is relatively positioned:

```
#myPage {
    position: relative;
}

#myOverlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}

#myOverlay.fixed {
    position: fixed;
}
```

**HTML examples**

To cover the *#myPage* element with the overlay (see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEmyP/1/)):

```
<div id="myPage">
    <p>This will be covered by the overlay</p>
    <div id="myOverlay"></div>
</div>
```

To cover the entire body, i.e. viewport, put the overlay element right before the closing tag of `body` and use fixed positioning (see on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uEmyP/)):

```
<body>
    <div id="myPage"></div>
    <div id="myOverlay" class="fixed"></div>
</body>
```

**JavaScript method to get entire document**

To get the entire height of the document (even that what is outside of the viewport) you can use [James Padolseys solution](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/get-document-height-cross-browser/) which is very simple and works across all browsers:

```
$.getDocHeight = function(){
    return Math.max(
        $(document).height(),
        $(window).height(),
        /* For opera: */
        document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using :

```
$(document).height();
```

Don't have time to test it now, but check it out.